# boost::shared_ptr and dynamic cast

Tags: c++, boost, dynamic-cast, boost-smart-ptr

I have a problem using a `shared_ptr` of a base class, I can't seem to be able to call the derived class's methods when dereferencing it. I believe code will be more verbose than me:

```
class Base : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<Base>
{
  public:
    typedef  boost::shared_ptr<BabelNet> pointer;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
  public:
     static pointer  create()
                {
                        return pointer(new Derived);
                }
     void             anyMethod()
     {
        Base::pointer foo = Derived::create();
        // I can't call any method of Derived with foo
        // How can I manage to do this ?
        // is dynamic_cast a valid answer ?
        foo->derivedMethod(); // -> compilation fail
     }

};
```

Comment: It would help if your example was compilable, of course with the offending line commented.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

see [static_cast with boost::shared_ptr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624854/static-cast-with-boostshared-ptr)

you'll need to use [dynamic_pointer_cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#dynamic_pointer_cast) to get the appropriate `shared_ptr` instantiation. (corresponding to a `dynamic_cast`)

Comment: Why not `static_pointer_cast`? I guess maybe the example isn't representative of the real code, but the example doesn't need a dynamic cast (because the object is of the target type), and doesn't allow one (because neither class has any virtual functions).

Comment: I put `dynamic_pointer_cast` because of the title of the post, actually. But yes, in his code, a `static_pointer_cast` will do.

Comment: Right, thanks to you I've found an interesting article: http://nealabq.com/blog/2008/11/26/pointer_cast/ if I just use a shared_ptr to the derived_class, I can pass it as a shared_ptr to the base class, neat.

Answer (score 4):

Shared pointer or not, when you have a pointer to a `Base`, you can only call member functions from `Base`.

If you really need to `dynamic_cast`, you can use `dynamic_pointer_cast` from [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm), but chances are that you shouldn't. Instead, think about your design : **`Derived` is a `Base`**, and this is an extremely strong relationship, so think carefully about `Base` interface and if the concrete type really has to be known.

Answer (score 1):

If derivedMethod is not declared in base class (virtual or not), then it is normal that the compilation would fail. The shared ptr knows and uses the base class (through the pointer it holds), and knows nothing about the derived class and its specific methods.

Comment: If the pointer was a typedef of the derived class, could it be upcasted so that an external class can only know about Base::pointer ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code wouldn't work even with raw pointers.

You need either to declare `derivedMethod()` method even in base class or to have a pointer to  a`Derived` object.