# shared ptr casting

Tags: c++, boost, casting, shared-ptr

```
class Object { };
Class Derived : public Object { };

boost::shared_ptr<Object> mObject(new Derived); // Ok
```

But how to cast it to `boost::shared_ptr<Derived>` ?

I tried something like: `static_cast< boost::shared_ptr<Derived> >(mObject)` and it failed.

The only working idea is:

`boost::shared_ptr<Derived> res(new dynamic_cast<Derived*>(mObject.get()))`

Comment: possible duplicate of [static_cast with boost::shared_ptr?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/624854/static-cast-with-boostshared-ptr)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

DO NOT pass the result of the cast to a new shared_ptr constructor. This will result in two shared_ptrs thinking they own the object, and both will try to delete it. The result will be a double-free, and a likely crash.

shared_ptr has [cast functions](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#static_pointer_cast) specifically for this.

Comment: `shared_ptr`s don't, alone, "own" anything. However, you're right in suggesting that each `shared_ptr` will not be aware that the other has a share in the ownership claim.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
class Object { };
Class Derived : public Object { };

boost::shared_ptr<Object> mObject = new Derived; // OK
boost::shared_ptr<Derived> mDerived = 
    boost::static_pointer_cast<Derived, Object>(mObject); // OK
```

Boost has the corresponding templates to fulfill the standard casts defined in c++.