# C++ - Smart Pointers - Passing derived class shared pointer to base through template

Tags: c++, boost, smart-pointers

I have the following and having difficulty resolving the error please help.

i have the following class as template definition somewhere.

```
template<class ConcreteHandlerType>
class SomeAcceptor: public ACE_Acceptor<ConcreteHandlerType, ACE_SOCK_Acceptor>
```

In some other file, i initialize this class in the constructor

```
class initialize {

    typedef SomeAcceptor<BaseClassSomeHandler> baseAcceptor_t;
    typedef SomeAcceptor<DerivedClassSomeHandler> derivedAcceptor_t;
    boost::shared_ptr<baseAcceptor_t;> mAcceptor;   
    boost::shared_ptr<derivedAcceptor_t;> mDerivedAcceptor;   

    bool HandleAcceptNotification(BaseClassSomeHandler& someHandler);

    initialize() : mAcceptor(0), mDerivedAcceptor(new DerivedAcceptor_t) {
        mAcceptor->SetAcceptNotificationDelegate(fastdelegate::MakeDelegate(this, &initialize::HandleAcceptNotification));
    }
}
```

Error i get is

```
error: no matching function for call to `boost::shared_ptr<SomeAcceptor<BaseClassSomeHandler> >::shared_ptr(int)'common/lib/boost_1_39_0/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:160: note: candidates are: boost::shared_ptr<SomeAcceptor<BaseClassSomeHandler> >::shared_ptr(const boost::shared_ptr<SomeAcceptor<BaseClassSomeHandler> >&)
common/lib/boost_1_39_0/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:173: notboost::shared_ptr<T>::shared_ptr() [with T = SomeAcceptor<BaseClassSomeHandler>]
```

I also tried overloading the function with
        bool HandleAcceptNotification(DerivedClassSomeHandler& someHandler);

but because mAcceptor is of type SomeAcceptor BaseClassSomeHandler, i get this error, but to fix this.

I guess i need to cast it somehow, but how to do it?

i tried doing like below inside the constructor and it didn't work

```
    initialize() : mAcceptor(0), mDerivedAcceptor(new DerivedAcceptor_t) {

        mAcceptor = mDerivedAcceptor;   // Error here

        mAcceptor->SetAcceptNotificationDelegate(fastdelegate::MakeDelegate(this, &initialize::HandleAcceptNotification));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code, it looks like you want `mAcceptor` to be assigned NULL (0), if that is the case you don't need to initialize it at all, as the default constructor will take care of that.  But, since you call a function on that (NULL) pointer immediately, its not immediately clear exactly what you want to do.

If you want `mAcceptor` and `mDerivedAcceptor` to point to the same (shared) object and assuming `DerivedClassSomeHandler` is derived from `BaseClassSomeHandler`, this is a situation where you should use `boost::shared_static_cast`, as described [here](http://tweakbits.com/articles/sharedptr/index.html).

There's also some good information in [this apparently related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624854/static-cast-with-boostshared-ptr).

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to the `mAcceptor(0)` in

```
initialize() : mAcceptor(0), mDerivedAcceptor(new DerivedAcceptor_t) {
    mAcceptor->SetAcceptNotificationDelegate(fastdelegate::MakeDelegate(this, &initialize::HandleAcceptNotification));
}
```

The smart_ptr default constructor assigns the wrapped ptr to NULL, so leave out mAcceptor(0) from the initialization list.

Answer (score 0):

`boost::shared_ptr<SomeAcceptor<BaseClassSomeHandler> >::shared_ptr(int)`

It's yelling at you that there's no constructor that accepts an **int**.

Just use: **mAcceptor()**